# Measure Image Load Time: PerformanceResourceTiming

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm trying to measure the speed of the load time of an image (how long it actually takes the image to fully load at full resolution on a user's browser).

I was wondering if the Performance Resource Timing in the window.performance JavaScript was good for doing this, if you recommend it, or if you recommend something else (also preferably JavaScript because I'd like this to be browser-only as I'd like people to test it from different locations as well).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have jquery

```
var startTime = +new Date();
$("#img").attr({"src": imgURI});
var endTime = +new Date();
var finalTime=endTime - startTime;
```

Alternatively.

```
var tempImg=getElementById("img");
var startTime = +new Date();
var endTime;
var finalTime;

tempImg.onload = function () {
    endTime = +new Date();
    finalTime=endTime - startTime
}
tempImg.src = imgURI;
```

Either way it has to be done to an image that is being displayed, not to an in memory image.  In memory it will be almost instant.  But there is a delay in rendering and DOM recalculations that you would want to factor in to your calculations.

Comment: Can you explain more about the DOM recalculations and delay in rendering? Also, I assume this would be an image that is displayed because it is a website that will be loading for visitors.

Comment: Basically if the image tags size and width weren't stated explicitly, then when the image loads, the DOM has to reshuffle everything to make it fit.  This causes recalculations that, especially on mobile devices, can take a long time.
Also on mobile devices you can see a lag as images display, especially base64 images.  This delay may not be that critical, but if your looking to measure it end to end, then it should probably be considered.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="loadResources()">
    <script>
        function loadResources()
        {
           var start = new Date().getTime();
           var image1 = new Image();
           var resourceTiming = function() {
               var now = new Date().getTime();
               var latency = now - start;
               alert("End to end qresource fetch: " + latency);
           };

           image1.onload = resourceTiming;
           image1.src = 'https://yourwebsite/Icons/image.png';
        }
    </script>
    <img src="https://yourwebsite/Icons/image_2.png">
  </body>
```

or

```
<body onload="loadResources()">
    <script>
       function loadResources()
       {
          var image1 = new Image();
          image1.onload = resourceTiming;
          image1.src = 'https://yourwebsite/Icons/image.png';
       }

       function resourceTiming()
       {
           var resourceList = window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource");
           for (i = 0; i < resourceList.length; i++)
           {
              if (resourceList[i].initiatorType == "img")
              {
                 alert("End to end resource fetch: "+ resourceList[i].responseEnd - resourceList[i].startTime);
              }
           }
       }
    </script>
    <img id="image0" src="https://yourwebsite/Icons/image_2.png">   </body>
```

Please refer the implementation https://jsfiddle.net/q4euntat/5/

Comment: When I run this code on my own test outside of JSfiddle it always gives 0.00 on the first run, and then starts showing load in ms after the image is cached. Thoughts?